# EF 5.0 Code First navigation property null for only one property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I seem to be having a problem with the following model using EF 5.0 CodeFirst:

[image]

When I try and do a listing with SalesPlanActivity I am unable to get the Activity name from the navigational property

i.e. If my model is SalesPlanActivity, model.Activity <--- is null, yet model.Company and model.SalesPlan are fine.

The idea is that a company has a library of activities, each company has a number of salesplans, each salesplans has a number of activities (which come from the activity library)

**Am I mapping this incorrectly?**

**Should the mapping between SalesPlanActivity and Activity be 1:1?**

I've added the following relationships

```
 // Relationships
        modelBuilder.Entity<SalesPlanActivity>().HasRequired(t => t.Activity)
            .WithMany(t => t.SalesPlanActivities)                
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.CompanyId, d.ActivityId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SalesPlanActivity>().HasRequired(t => t.SalesPlan)
            .WithMany(t => t.SalesPlanActivities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.SalesPlanId, d.CompanyId });


 public class Activity : IAuditable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activity Name"), Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesPlanActivity> SalesPlanActivities { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IAuditable
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name"), Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesPlan> SalesPlans { get; set; }        

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class SalesPlan : IAuditable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SalesPlanId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sales Plan Name"), Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total Points"), Required]
    public decimal TotalPoints { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesPlanActivity> SalesPlanActivities { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class SalesPlanActivity : IAuditable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SalesPlanId { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesPlan SalesPlan { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }        

    public decimal Points { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: from your example, youre right it looks like it should be 1:1 but i dont think this is stopping it working. Can you check its loading correctly by using eager loading `.Include(s=>s.Activity)` in your salesPlanActivity query?

Comment: Hi Luke, I did try that and got nothing coming back at all, I'm wondering how I could make it a 1:1 anyway?

Comment: basically this 1:1 is actually not possible in sql (one row has to be inserted first) but most people mean 1: 0-1 when they say 1:1 modelBuilder.Entity<SalesPlanActivity>().HasRequired(t => t.Activity).WithOptional(t => t.SalesPlanActivity);

Comment: That's what I tried before but then I got:
Invalid column name 'Activity_ActivityId'.
Invalid column name 'Activity_CompanyId'.
I tried using .Map() to map the keys but it said they were already defined

Comment: I managed to get everything working by removing my relationship and defining all keys in code